# Field extension of degree $p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm struggling with the following problem.

Let n be a natural number, let $F$ be a field that contains a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity and let $a \in F^{\times}$. Show that if deg$(F(\sqrt[p]{a})/F) >1$, then deg$(F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F)=p^n$.

I was able to show that deg$(F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F)>1$ (this is because deg$(F(\sqrt[p]{a})/F) >1$) and that $F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F$ is Galois ($F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F$ is separable because $F$ contains a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity and normal because $X^{p^n} -a$ splits over $F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F)$).

I thus tried to show that |Gal($F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F)| = p^n$ since |Gal($F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F)| =$  deg$(F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F)$. But this is where I failed (I tried to show that the map Gal($F(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/F \rightarrow \mu_{p^n}$ is surjective).

If someone could help me with a hint, that would be kind.

Comment: You will have to use that $p$ is prime somewhere -- you don't even state that, but without this assumption the claim is wrong. Try to do $n=1$ first. Then $n=2$, and maybe a general idea for induction shows up.

Comment: Let $f_n \in F[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $a^{1/p^n}$ and $\zeta$ the primitive $p^n$-th root of unity then (since $f_n(x)$ divides $x^{p^n}-a$) $f_n(x) = \prod_{j=1}^m (x-\zeta^{e_j} a^{1/p^n})$ thus $f_n(0) = ...$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Reuns. Is the following right:
We want $|f_n(0)|=|a|$, and then we see that we must have $m=p^n$ ?

Comment: We want $f_n(0) = \prod_{j=1}^m \zeta^{e_j} a^{1/p^n} \in F$ so $(a^{1/p^n})^m \in F$ whence $m = p^n$ and $e_j = j$

Comment: Thank you for your help! So there is no need to appeal to the Galois Group of the extension at all here actually. It is enough to see that $P(X) = X^{p^n} - a = \Pi_{i=1}^{p^n} X - \zeta^{i}a^{1/p^n}$ and then to note that the $f_n$ must divide $P$. Evaluating $f_n$ at 0 finally allows us to conclude. Is that right ?